# How to send mail using Tmail?

Tags: php, atk4

I went though the Tmail class but i dont how to load a template. can any body provide me a sample example...

Comment: TMail is an email handler library for Ruby, not PHP.

Comment: It's also class in Agile Toolkit http://agiletoolkit.org

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

$mail=$this->add('TMail');
$mail->loadTemplate('test-mail');

There is an article in the official site of atk4:

http://agiletoolkit.org/blog/tmail/

Best regards.